# Why aren't mages trusted to remove their own limiters?

Tags: nanoha

In Nanoha StrikerS (season 3), several of the high-end mages had [limiters](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Limiter) imposed on them to limit their power output thereby reducing their mage rank levels:

- [Nanoha Takamachi](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Nanoha_Takamachi) - S+ reduced to AA.
- [Fate Testarossa](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Fate_Testarossa) - S+ reduced to AA.
- [Hayate Yagami](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Hayate_Yagami) - SS reduced to A.
- [Lutecia Alphine](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Lutecia_Alpine) - S reduced to D?

The purpose of the limiters was to limit the damage that could be caused to a small area and possibly to protect the mages themselves from overexerting.

Furthermore, limiters can only be removed by a high-ranked official.

With the exception of Lutecia (who was a captured antagonist), why were the mages not trusted to remove their own limiters if their purpose was to prevent **accidental** collateral damage?

Comment: If they could remove it themselves, what would be the point of even having a limiter?

Comment: The limiters are there to prevent **accidental** misuse. It's like a safety lock for guns. There to prevent misfiring. But when you need it, you are free to remove it.

Comment: I have a feeling it's to limit damage if they 'accidentally' go rogue.  Similar to how the military requires weapons to be checked-out of an armory (and ICBMs need multiple people to be launched).

Comment: I took it to be because the mages are like walking nuclear weapons (probably more destructive in the case of a really angry S+ mage). I'm sure any military command would feel safer with a lock on their strategic weapons!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This limiter is in place because high-end mages' powers become *so* powerful that they can present a danger simply by being unrestrained.

When a group of mages are in close proximity, or are working together, they *must* be limited. Because of their high amount of power, this much energy (mana) in one area would endanger the fabric of time-space (the series's equivalent of *space–time*).<sup>[[*Nanoha* Wiki]](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Limiter)</sup> So consider, if mages were to be allowed to remove these limiters without consent of the [TSAB](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/TSAB), they may do it unscrupulously, which could lead to unpredictable damage.

This is compared to a parallel in real life, where incredibly powerful weapons are sealed away for emergency; not every soldier on the battlefield has a rocket launcher because that would just lead to destruction (and high costs!).

> This is similar to how a normal organization is restricted from carrying excessive weaponry during normal missions, only using such equipment in times of emergency.<sup>[[DVD Booklet translation]](http://asnano.wordpress.com/2007/10/07/nanoha-strikers-dvd-3-booklet/)</sup>

TV Tropes calls this [Awesomeness Is Volatile](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AwesomenessIsVolatile), stating that "*they'd run the risk of having their sheer combined power potentially warping the fabric of reality*" and "*[Hayate, Nanoha, and Fate] alone pretty much constitute an army*".